# Responsive pixel perfect markup

Tags: css, responsive-design, cross-browser, pixel-perfect

Client want the subject.

I have psd for a different screen sizes (mobile, tablet and desktop), but I not allowed simply use media queries, because in between those sizes content should be the same as in the psd.

I tried using script that would change root `font-size`, based on window.innerWidth and innerHeight, so I could just use `em` to scale everything, but had consistent results on all browsers and platforms.

**So what is a best way to do responsive pixel perfect markup?**

Comment: web media is not print media, your client should understand this. Beside who would notice the difference, what matters is not the pixel

Comment: a screen shot or serving  pdf would do the pixel perfect ..... but that's for print

Comment: I totally agree, but client don't understand this :(